# Post locked - Why?

Tags: discussion, spam

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/30646/revisions

Why was this post just locked and deleted?  It is a valid puzzle that some of us are looking at.  Is it because someone took a glance at it and thought it was jibberish?

What happened?

Answer (score 5):

It is connected to a suspension evasion.

(When a suspended user attempts to evade a suspension and continue to post content, that content will be removed.)

Comment: OK - fair enough.  Out of curiosity, how do you know that this user is evading a suspension?  IP address?

Comment: Because the reason given is misleading - spam/offensive.  It was neither.

Comment: @Trenin _We have our wayss...._ -- in reality, we can't really go into details on exactly how these tools work internally, but they're pretty good at what they do. The Community lock is a possible side consequence of that.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know why there are a bunch of deleted questions being marked as spam/offensive when they aren't. Like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30312) and [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/30000/).

Comment: @f'' It's unfortunate, but this user has been pretty persistent for a little more than a month now (and probably longer). I hate to do it, because it kills the work that goes into these questions, but without it suspensions just aren't meaningful.

Comment: Seems like we could use another close reason...One that cannot be voted on.

Comment: @Khale The function of a suspension is that a user cannot interact with the site for the duration of their suspension. Leaving the posts up doesn't really... achieve that.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I suggest you make a new meta post suggesting that.  I flagged that particular question for reopening, because I thought a bot had mistaken it for spam and closed it.  If the close reason was more apropos, I wouldn't have flagged it.

Comment: I wish I could find the one from a week(?) or so ago - it was a really good question, but alas she is gone

Comment: You all do have a point, I think - would it help if I started leaving an explanatory comment when a question is removed for this reason?

Comment: Also, if this is connected to a suspension, why aren't any of the involved accounts suspended?

Comment: @Emrakul, Yes, that would help.  Although a different close reason would be even better, since the question is neither spam nor offensive.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain For internal reasons, this is the way I've been doing it... I'm going to double check to make sure I'm handling this correctly, though, from a technical perspective.

Comment: @Emrakul This may possibly be grounds for a new question, but is there a way to delete these posts without those that have answered the question and gained rep from it losing said rep?

Comment: @AggieKidd Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to do that within the current system. I'm hoping the problem goes away soon, though; it seems to be quieting down lately.

Comment: @Emrakul Agreed. I just noticed today because I happened to be the one that lost the rep. Fortunately I didn't lose the badge.